# Is their any way to stream sdp file from rtsp server in iPhone 4.0 sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios4, video-streaming

I am working on a project in which I need to stream an sdp file from rtsp server. And play it in my application on iPhone. I searched hard through out the web but could not found any possible way to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only 2 ways I know of to do this are:

1: use ffmpeg to convert the stream to ts files, either on the server or locally.
2: Use wowza (wowzamedia.com) to convert the stream to an iOS compatible http live stream.

The latter is much easier to set up, but costs money, whereas the ffmpeg option would probably be lower quality, but could be set up for free.